# Period of $f(x)\tan\left(\frac{\pi[x]}{2}\right)$

Tags: trigonometry

What is the Fundamental period of $$f(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi[x]}{2}\right)$$ where $[.]$ is Greatest Integer function.

My Try: $[x+k]=[x]+k$    for any integer $k$

So $$[x+2]=[x]+2$$
and since $\tan(x)$ is Periodic with period $\pi$, The Period of $f(x)$ is $2$